# HorizontalScrollViews scrolling together

Tags: android, scroll, scrollview, horizontalscrollview

I need to scroll 2 parallel HorizontalScrollView dependently, which means that if I'm scrolling one, the other one should scroll too.

How can I do such a thing?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi Thomaus, Did you solve this problem?

Comment: Hi Thomaus, I have solved this problem.

Comment: Can you post the answer please?

Comment: Thomaus please follow this link. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16707063/in-android-how-to-set-the-scroll-speed-in-scrollview

Answer (score 0):

```
hscrollViewOne=(HorizontalScrollView)findViewById(R.id.hsvOne);
hscrollViewTwo=(HorizontalScrollView)findViewById(R.id.hsvTwo);


hscrollViewOne.setOnScrollChangeListener(new View.OnScrollChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onScrollChange(View v, int scrollX, int scrollY, int oldScrollX, int oldScrollY) {
            hscrollViewTwo.scrollTo(scrollX, scrollY);
        }
    });

hscrollViewTwo.setOnScrollChangeListener(new View.OnScrollChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onScrollChange(View v, int scrollX, int scrollY, int oldScrollX, int oldScrollY) {
            hscrollViewOne.scrollTo(scrollX,scrollY);
        }
    });
```