# Scroll another HorizontalScrollView though one is scrolling in android

Tags: android, scrollview, horizontal-scrolling, horizontalscrollview

I have two `HorizontalScrollView`s. If the user scrolls one ScrollView, the other ScrollView should also get scrolled. I am new to android and I wonder to know how can I achieve this?

Comment: Is your  elements in both scrollview same numbers.

Comment: yes they are same...!!

Comment: See here. I think its perfect answer for you : http://stackoverflow.com/a/35147649/1621789

Answer (score 0):

If you want your two different scrollviews to scroll at the same time it means you only need one scroll view in which you cand put the content within the ones you have now. Try do make thinghs as simple as you can

Comment: I cant, because my requirement is different.

Answer (score 0):

Extend HorizontalScrollview like this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6462630/1124160

onScroll in first ScrollView: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/HorizontalScrollView.html#scrollTo(int, int)

Scroll the second one.

Answer (score 0):

If your have number of items save in both `HorizontalScrollView` , then create a `GridView` and give number of columns equals to element in one `HorizontalScrollView`. In this way you can achieve your goal.